# I dont know why Debug Error abort() has been called and it breaks at stoi

Tags: c++

Sorry if i mess this post up. First timer here. I'm hoping someone can really help me.In Album.cpp is where my read function is, I think the problem is coming from there, specifically from `min = stoi(temp);` But heres the thing. 
`. My friends have a very similar code if not identical except for the variable names. And everytime i run my Main.cpp I get an error about a debug error and abort(). I checked the debugger on` min = stoi(temp); ` and it didnt show it having any values even though i use it alot in the program to hold values. I then just made temp = '0'; just to see if it will go on without the error and it does! The program doest do what i need it to do but theres no error. I just dont know why this is?

Main.cpp

```
int main() 
{
    Song total;
    int choice;
    string m_filename;
    Album x;
    cout << "Album Program" << endl;
    cout << "----------" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Read ablbum info from a file" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Write album info to a file" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Show all album info on screen" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Show ablum time on screen" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter File Name: ";
    cin >> m_filename;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        x.Read(m_filename);
        cout << "Enter Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        break;
{
```

Album.cpp

```
  void Album::Read(string filename)
{

    string temp;
    ifstream Read;
    Read.open(filename);

    getline(Read, Title);
    getline(Read, temp);
    m_Artist.SetName(temp);
    getline(Read, temp);
    m_Artist.SetCountryofOrigin(temp);


    //temp = '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Time m_Time;
        int sec;
        int min;
        getline(Read, temp);
        S[i].SetTitle(temp);

        getline(Read, temp);

        min = stoi(temp);
        m_Time.SetMinutes(min);

        getline(Read, temp);

        sec = stoi(temp);
        m_Time.SetSeconds(sec);

        S[i].SetTime(m_Time);

    }
}
```

Comment: A handy habit to get into, plus a way to make this post more readable, is to try to come up with a [mcve]. Likely as you do so, you will solve your problem (which is a great skill set to have), but otherwise, you will have a few lines of code that reproduce your problem that we'd be able to answer

Comment: What is the format of the input data?  Please edit your post with a sample.

Comment: What is the value of `temp` at the `min = stoi(temp);` statement?  See [`stoi` exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: Thankyou for letting me know. I will try to work on a minimal version with the same problem. I wanted to do that in the first place but i have 4.h and 4.cpp in the static library so i honestly didnt know how to make it simpler to show. But in the debugger its saying the value of temp is nothing. Like temp = ""; I'm assuming thats might be why im having this problem.

Comment: And my input file is just a text file that looks like this 


Continued Silence  
Imagine Dragons  
USA  
Radioactive  
3  
6  
Demons  
2  
57  
On Top of the World  
3  
12  
Round and Round  
3  
17  
It's Time  
4  
0  
My Fault  
2  
56
I'm sorry idk how toformat it right in here.